# How to edit eclipse splash screen text?

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way I can edit the text on splash screen in eclipse. I want to brand eclipse splash screen with some changes in default text and icons.

Comment: [This article](https://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Branding/branding-your-application.html) covers all aspects of branding an Eclipse derivative product.

Comment: Hi Greg, I already have gone through the tutorial but it requires me use a rcp application. What I am trying to do is to change the existing eclipse I have.

Comment: Eclipse jars are signed, you can't easily modify them. Eclipse is just a RCP so you can make an new RCP which is just Eclipse with a new product branding.